# Optimal set-up of rewards for betting on an elemination game

Tags: probability-theory, game-theory, gambling

There is an elemination game with 10 unkown players.
There are 8 rounds.
At the end of each of the first 7 rounds, 1 player is eliminated.
In the last round, the winner will be decided between the remaining 3 players.

After every round (of the first 7 rounds) gamblers can bet on the eventual winner.
Also, after every round, more is known about the players, so it's more impressive if you know at the beginning of the tournament already who is going to win.
How should we arrange the pay-outs for the bets?
Should we force people to pick exactly on potential winner every round or allow for indecision/more involved strategies?

(I know this is maybe a bit involved but if someone knows pointers to the right theory, I think I might be able to work it out on my own. I just don't know what to search for and I don't find the right theory with the most obvious searches.)

Comment: What is the goal here?  You're asking about optimal rewards, but what does it mean for the rewards to be "optimal"?

Comment: The goal is to estimate how good the betters are at predicting the eventual winner. The optimal strategy for the betters should be to bet on their best guess that also reveals their degree of belief that they are correct. The money they have at the end should indicate how good they are at estimating. 
There is also the fact that early correct predictions should be rewarded. At first I thought about scaling this linearly, but in the stock market it is exponential, so maybe that is more natural.